# Image processing to make the sky clear and bluer using opencv, deep learning (python)

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have a few outdoor pictures before and after editing by a professional. However, I am trying to do the same thing using the deep learning and the openCV in python. Can someone suggest how to proceed?

(Right side is raw image and left side is edited using photoshop tools)

[link to 1st pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGSL8.jpg)
[link to 2nd pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEI20.jpg)

Comment: You won't need deep learning for that, probably just some colour and contrast changes

Comment: As a starting point, you can simply take the image difference to learn what the editor has done.

Comment: Is that the actual image you gave to the professional? Or did you actually give him a DNG/raw image?

Comment: No, I gave the raw unedited image to professional. Pictures in the given link I have created for easy comparison. My job is to find a way (algorithm) to map from right to left side of the image given in the link.

Comment: "Eerie" is the best word I can come up with for this. There's a clear, blue sky, yet there are no shadows anywhere.

Comment: Mmmm... how can we map from something we can't see and don't have? If the information isn't there because you have given us a burnt out 8-bit file instead of the 12/14 bits you actually started with, we can't recover them - we aren't magicians :-)